# auto-fold deeply nested parts of a file (vimscript)

Tags: vimscript

Folding in vim has bugged me for a while. What I intuitively want is for the details to be folded, but the overall structure of a file to remain unfolded. This way I can navigate around a file to see the structure quickly, and open folded sections when I need to dive into the details.

What I have been doing before today was to set the default fold level per filetype, in the `ftplugin`. For example `bash.vim` will have `foldlevel=1` whereas `python.vim` will be 2 or 3. But what I really want is for my editor to autodetect the complexity of the code and adjust the fold level accordingly.

My first attempt was just to calculate the maximum fold level for a file and just fold the most deeply nested parts:

```
:let &foldlevel = max(map(range(1, line('$')), 'foldlevel(v:val)'))-1
```

But this code has 2 problems:

1. If there is one complex part that is deeply nested it only folds that part. I'd prefer folding of anything that is nested deeper than the average for the file.
2. I scans the whole file. This may be a concern for very large files

After a lot of fiddling and trial and error I came up with this

```
function setfolds()
    " default fold level to slightly higer than the average fold level
    let b:fl_lines = min([line('$'), 250])
    let b:fl_levels = map(range(1, b:fl_lines), 'foldlevel(v:val)')
    exe 'let b:fl_sum = ' . join(b:fl_levels, '+')
    let b:fl_avg = b:fl_sum / (b:fl_lines * 1.0) " convert to float
    let b:fl_ceil = 0 + string(ceil(b:fl_avg)) " convert to int
    let &foldlevel = max([b:fl_ceil, 2])
endfunction
```

This is my first real (not copypasted) vimscript and I find it is super hacky and ugly.

1. is `exe` on a concatenated string really the best way to sum an array of integers in vimscript? Is there some kind of reduce pattern I could use instead?
2. conversion: multiply by `1.0` to convert to float. `+string()` to convert back to int?
3. Is it necessary to prefix vars with `b:` scope? Good practice or just superfluous?
4. Seems like setting folding will cause the whole file to be iterated over anyway. Should I just not worry about it?